# section as default element in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

when you don't specify the element a div is rendered by default. Is there an easy way to change the default element?

example:

```
#someid
  p
    lorem ispum
```

will render

```
<div id="someid"><p>lorem ipsum<p></div>
```

but in this case, i would like to get

```
<section id="someid"><p>lorem ipsum<p></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative. That DIV is hardwired into the way HAML is built. You would need to fork the project and change that, which would mean you change all of your divs to sections.

[Here is the HAML parser on Github.](https://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/parser.rb)

Comment: so no there is no easy way :P would be nice to have this in a config file! Thank you

Comment: I agree. It seems to be a fairly intrusive 'convention over configuration' decision, but on the other hand, it's probably more semantic to have the generic be the default, and be specific when you don't want to be generic.

Comment: yes sure, but i write more and more HTML5 and less div's so it was thinking it could me handy. But i just gonna wait that someone else forks into the project. I'm not very handy with ruby.